# Determining how much I should be paying for gas per week

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I go $110$ miles each week.
Gas costs $\$2.19$ per gallon.
My vehicle gas mileage is $18$ miles to the gallon.

How much am I paying per week?

Comment: Also, looking at Elliot G's answer, notice how the units cancel out, leaving your answer in $/week ("how much am I paying per week?"). Looking at the units will help you put together a solution.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{110~\mathrm{ miles}}{1~\mathrm{ week}}\cdot\frac{1~\mathrm{  gallon}}{18~\mathrm{  miles}}\cdot \frac{2.19~\mathrm{ $}}{1
~\mathrm{  gallon}}$$